Model exposure-time vs gain relationship
Cameras can increase exposure either by applying gain or by increasing exposure-time and I would like to model this relationship.
For this, given a target exposure, I measured the necessary exposure-time for different values of gain (resulting in equi-exposure line) in various illumination conditions. Here are the different equi-exposure lines.

I have trouble identifying what type of function it is. Additionally, I'd like to find it's parameters. Does someone have an idea on how to proceed?
PS: I was not sure which stackexchange community fitted the best this question, please kindly tell me if you think there's a better suited community and I will move the question there.

Reading camera documentation, I found that gain was expressed in dB. Let use $G$ for representing the gain and $T$ for the exposure-time, the relationship linking the two is:
$$G(T) = 20*log_{10}\left(\frac{T_0}{T}\right)$$
where $T_0$ is the exposure-time that would be required to have the scene correctly illuminated at $G=0$.
And indeed, for each illumination condition, finding the $T_0$ that best fits the data points gives a very good model of what was observed

